# Jelly or flavored Gelatin

Tags: substitutions, gelatin

I have found some American recipes that call for a pkt of flavored gelatin. Is this the same thing aswhat we call in Australia as jelly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you know as jelly in Australia is called flavored gelatin in the US. Jell-O is the most predominant US brand. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin_dessert) the equivalent in Australia would be Aeroplane Jelly.